# Formulário de contato não envia alguns campos de dados

Tags: php, html, formulário

Gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês , já verifiquei em tudo aqui mas não consegui detectar o erro, o formulário não consegue enviar os dados inseridos nos campos mensagem e selecione, ou seja eles chegam vazios no email.

```
<h2 class="main-heading">
             Entre em Contato Conosco
        </h2>
        <div class="divider-1"></div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md6 col-xs-12">
            <form method="post" class="contac-form" action="enviar.php">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="sr-only-focusable">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Nome">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="sr-only-focusable">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tel" class="sr-only-focusable">Telefone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" id="tel" required="required" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datevento" class="sr-only-focusable">Data do Evento</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="datevento" id="datevento" required="required" placeholder="Data do Evento">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="hevento" class="sr-only-focusable">Horário do Evento</label>
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="hevento" id="hevento" required="required" placeholder="Horário do Evento">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="devento" class="sr-only-focusable">Duração do Evento</label>
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="devento" id="devento" required="required" placeholder="Duração do Evento">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="endevento" class="sr-only-focusable">Endereço do Evento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endevento" id="endevento" required="required" placeholder="Endereço do Evento">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="select">Selecione o Brinquedo</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <select class="form-control" id="select">
                           <option value="1">Basquete Eletrônio</option>
                           <option value="2">Cama Elástica Pequenao</option>
                           <option value="3">Cama Elástica Média</option>
                           <option value="4">Cama Elástica Grande</option>
                           <option value="5">Castelo Pula Pula Médio</option>
                           <option value="6">Castelo Pula Pula Gigante Bolha</option>
                           <option value="7">Futebol de Sabão</option>
                           <option value="8">Filmagem Aérea</option>
                           <option value="10">Locação de Som</option>
                           <option value="11">Mini Tobogã</option>
                           <option value="12">Máquina de Algodão Doce</option>
                           <option value="13">Modelagem com Balão</option>
                           <option value="14">Pintura Facial</option>
                           <option value="15">Pipoqueira Elétrica</option>
                           <option value="16">Piscina de Bolinha Inflável</option>
                           <option value="17">Piscina de Bolinha Casinha</option>
                           <option value="18">Quick Massagem para Festa</option>
                           <option value="19">Recreação</option>
                       </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Mensagem</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

esse é o código PHP

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Pedro
 * Date: 10/01/2017
 * Time: 09:45
 */


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel =  $_POST['tel'];
$datevento = $_POST['datevento'];
$hevento = $_POST['hevento'];
$devento = $_POST['devento'];
$endevento = $_POST['endevento'];
$select = $_POST['select'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$refresh = '<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1; url=form.html\" />';
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"E-mail inválido!.\")</script>';
    exit ($refresh);
} elseif
(!filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
{
    echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"E-mail inválido!. Contém caracteres não permitidos.\")</script>';
    exit ($refresh);
}

 ($name != '' && $email != '' && $tel  != '' && $message != '');

    $msg = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $name<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>E-mail:</strong> $email<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Telefone:</strong> $tel<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Data do Evento:</strong> $datevento<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Horário do Evento:</strong> $hevento<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Duração do Evento:</strong> $devento<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Endereço do Evento:</strong> $endevento<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Tipo de Brinquedo:</strong> $select<br>";
    $msg .= "<strong>Mensagem:</strong> $message<br>";
    $recipient = "contato@acontecerbrinquedos.com.br";
    $subject = "Formulário de Contato";
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "From: $email\r\n";


    (mail ($recipient, $subject, $msg, $header));

  echo "<p align=center>Mensagem Enviada com Sucesso!</p>";
echo "<p align=center>Retornaremos em breve!</p>";

echo "<script>window.location='index.html';alert('$name, sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso! Estaremos retornando em breve');</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Os campos são enviados pelo form baseando-se no atributo "name" do mesmo.

Nesse caso falta name no select e no textarea.

Comment: Cara valeu de mais deu certinho aqui muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Falta colocar o atributo "name" neles

```
 <select class="form-control" id="select" name="select">
 <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="6" name="message">  </textarea>
```

Testa ai

Comment: Cara valeu de mais deu certinho aqui muito obrigado pela ajuda